# How to sum the computed rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

**QUERY:**

```
   SELECT name, 
    Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (1,2) THEN  amnt END ) as part1, 
    Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (3,4) THEN amnt END )as part2, 
    Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (5,6) THEN amnt END )as part3,
    Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (7,8) THEN amnt END )as part4,
    Sum(CASE WHEN month(date)  in (9,10) THEN amnt END )as part5,
    Sum(CASE WHEN month(date)  in (11,12) THEN amnt END )as part6
   FROM table1 GROUP BY name;
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| name    | part1    |    part2 |    part3 |    part4 |    part5 |    part6 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| A       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |    29400 |
| B       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     1900 |
| C       |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |    16310 |
| D       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     8210 |
| E       |     1782 |     1782 |     1782 |     1782 |     3564 |     1782 |
| F       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     7700 |
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT - 1:** How to compute the total column which is the sum of the amounts present in each row of all segments?

```
--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+ ----------- +
| name    | part1    |    part2 |    part3 |    part4 |    part5 |    part6 |  Total    | 
+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| A       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |    29400 |  29400    |
| B       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     1900 |  1900     |
| C       |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |    16310 |  27960    |
| D       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     8210 |  8210     |
| E       |     1782 |     1782 |     1782 |     1782 |     3564 |     1782 |  12474    |
| F       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     7700 |  7700     |
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT - 2:** How to compute the total number of active parts, the part in which the value of the column is not NULL?

```
--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+ --------- +-------+
| name    | part1    |    part2 |    part3 |    part4 |    part5 |    part6 |  Total  | Active| 
                                                                                      | Parts |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+------
| A       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |    29400 |  29400  |  1    |
| B       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     1900 |  1900   |  1    |
| C       |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |     2330 |    16310 |  27960  |  6    |
| D       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     8210 |  8210   |  1    |
| E       |     1782 |     1782 |     1782 |     1782 |     3564 |     1782 |  12474  |  6    |
| F       |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     NULL |     7700 |  7700   |  1    |
```

Comment: What is a "segment"?

Comment: Segments are the parts, @GordonLinoff .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT name, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (1,2) THEN  amnt END ) as part1, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (3,4) THEN amnt END )as part2, 
       Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (5,6) THEN amnt END )as part3,
       Sum(CASE WHEN month(date) in (7,8) THEN amnt END )as part4,
       Sum(CASE WHEN month(date)  in (9,10) THEN amnt END )as part5,
       Sum(CASE WHEN month(date)  in (11,12) THEN amnt END )as part6,
       Sum(amnt) as total,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ceiling(month(date) / 2)) as num_periods
FROM table1
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: something like `bit_or(1 << ceiling(month(date) / 2))`

Comment: yes, I was proposing `bit_or...` for your sum_of_parts, though I didn't test it

Comment: just add `, bit_or(1 << ceiling(month(date) / 2)) as sum_of_parts` to your select list?  I'm not going to edit Gordon's query without actually trying it, and I can't do that right now

Comment: @arbitrary . . . I think you should ask a new question for this.